# Getting Zone.js related console error when loading index.html

Tags: angular

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW4ZW.jpg)   Below is the index.html code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Emp Profile</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

when try to access http://localhost:3000/ getting the below error,

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load %3Ch1%3E%20My%20first%20Employee%20app%20%3C/h1%3E at resolvePromise (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:665:31) [<root>] at resolvePromise (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:636:17) [<root>] at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:713:17 [<root>] at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:166:47) [<root> => <root>] at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:546:35) [<root>] at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:25) [<root>]
```

Please find the attached screenshot

Comment: This looks like an issue with your build process, since it's trying to load a file  which doesn't exist. You should post your webpack/system.js/whatever configuration here, since that's likely where the problem exists. Where did you get the configuration file, or template for your project?

Comment: thanks for the reply @adam,  wrongly mentioned templateUrl instead of template

Comment: Glad you figured it out! You should post an answer to your own question, to help anyone else who has a similar problem in the future.